# C# MVC: How to create model for multi step form?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have multi step form where user completes university registration:

In first form, student fills his personal details. (Name, Email, Mobile)
In second form, student fills marks obtained in high school. (Percentage)
In third form, student fills his parents details. (Name, Email, Mobile)

This finally gets saved to database.

I have created three partial views for these forms.

Should I create 1 c# model class that has all these fields and use it across the three partial views?

OR

Create separate c# model classes for each of these views?

Please note that these form steps may have different layout/number of fields on different platforms like desktop,mobile,apps i.e. we are planning to combine step1 and step2 on desktop and keep them as separate steps on mobile & apps.

Comment: create separate models for each of them and put them in a Viewmodel for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Do something Like

```
public class ViewModel
{
public basic BDetails{get;set;}
public Advanced ADetails{get;set;}
public Personal PDetails{get;set;}
}

public class basic{
.....
}

public class Advanced
{
....
}

public class Personal
{
......
}
```

use the ViewModel class as your View class

Comment: I am referring here to c# classes model, updated the same in question too to clarify.

Comment: i would go for a view model consisting of three different model here and sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

Separate Models and Database Tables.

I did a similar project for a secondary school and the original system was based on flat topography. There ended up being multiple children and redundant information as siblings were enrolled. The data was partially normalized into tables for families, students, schools, subjects and bridge tables to handle the 1:n and n:n relationships between them.

While this took a little longer to implement, it was easier when the system was enhanced to be more user friendly. Schools were pre-populated and able to be selected in a list; the same was done with subjects. Addresses were standardized to conform with post office specifications.

The end result was a very happy client. Besides uniformity of the information, duplicate emails and postal mailings were heavily reduced. They also contracted for further work to add in demographic reporting and identify their recruiting weaknesses and strengths. They contracted with a sister company for marketing too.

Comment: Hi, good to know this. But how would this solve my problem here?

Comment: Identify and create the models first, and do one view per model. I would start with the student and get their ID. Then the parents and check and create new if they dont exist. Get their ID, add to relationship table. Best thing to do if this is new concepts is to draw it out in a flowchart

Answer (score 0):

First off: I would suggest that you use one model for student and parent(since they have similar properties - Name, Email, Mobile). You could make a Person model and it could have the `enum` PersonType. PersonType should be Student or Parent:

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Mobile { get; set; }
   public PersonType Person { get; set; }
}

enum PersonType
{
   Student,
   Parent
}
```

Next off: only one view is necessary in your case. Use a ViewModel as the model for it. The ViewModel could look something like this:

```
public class VMStudentDetails
{
   public float Percentage { get; set; }
   public Person Student { get; set; }
   public Person Parent { get; set; } 
}
```